# ServiceMix and Camel OSGi Properties Component

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-servicemix

Is there a Camel Properties Component feature to install in ServiceMix? Because I can't find it so I can't load my OSGi bundle.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent not found from bundle [my-camel-osgi-bundle]
```

How can I install the Camel Properties Component feature in Apache ServiceMix?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My bad! Properties component is part of camel-core

Answer (score 1):

Camel Properties component is came with camel-core.

I think you just need to check your camel osgi bundle sets the import packages rightly.

Comment: What do you mean by checking if camel osgi bundle sets the import packages rightly?

Comment: Make sure your bundle imports package `org.apache.camel.component.properties`